# Difference between using "omp4j" and using Java's built in "Runnable" class

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I'm new to parallel computing. I just learned that "omp4j" is the equivalent of "openMP" in java.

After reading some articles, my main question is, what is the difference between using "omp4j" and using Java's built it "Runnbale" class to achieve multi threading?

Comment: omp4j is for compiling classes with preprocessing, do you mean openMP ?

Comment: Never heard of omp4j, but that's the same as asking "why openmp instead of pthreads?". Those are two different abstraction layers. But yes Java already has some decent high level threading abstractions so there's less need for something like openMP.